# Assembly less than

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

Im trying to recreate a "less than" function in AMD64 assembly.

Like in this case I wanna return 1 if the parameter in %rdi is less then 3.

```
        .globl f
        .type f, @function
f:
        xor %rax, %rax
        movq %rdi, %r10
        cmpq $3, %r10
        cmovlq $1, %rax
        ret
```

I have never used cmov before, and I am not sure if I am using it the right way. I get the following error:

`Error: suffix or operands invalid for cmovl`

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have consulted the instruction set reference. There is no `cmov` that allows an immediate operand, you need to use a register.

Comment: ok thanks, so if I put the `$1` into a register it should work like this?